# How to add something to scrollbar (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This is my python code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk


lst_action = ''
action = 'The Hack Hub has started.'

window = Tk()

window.title("Hack Hub")

window.resizable(height = 0, width = 0)

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab0 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab4 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.add(tab0, text='HackHub')
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Brute Force')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='IP Grabber')
tab_control.add(tab3, text='Logs')
tab_control.add(tab4, text='Settings')

def help_brf():
    tkinter.messagebox._show('How to make brf attack?','1.Wpisz do pola: nazwa/email nazwę lub email konta którego chcesz złamać hasło(zależnie od strony). 2.Wpisz ip strony. 3.Wybierz od jakiej do jakiej liczby hasło ma być wyszukiwane. 4.Kliknij rozpocznij atak oraz czekaj na rezultaty.')

def help_grabber():
    tkinter.messagebox._show('How to make ip grabber app:', '1.Enter your proton-mail. 2.Click create program.')

#Hacking Hub

lbl_a0 = Label(tab0, text= 'Welcome to the hack hub!')
lbl_a0.grid(column=0, row=0)

lbl_a1 = Label(tab0, text= 'If you found a bug or think something should be improved,\n send an email to this address: @ protonmail.ch')
lbl_a1.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl_a1 = Label(tab0, text= 'Enjoy!')
lbl_a1.grid(column=0, row=2)

#Brute Force

lbl_b0 = Label(tab1, text= 'name/email: ')
lbl_b0.grid(column=0, row=0)

e0 = Entry(tab1, bd=3)
e0.grid(column=1, row=0)


lbl_b1 = Label(tab1, text= 'website ip: ')
lbl_b1.grid(column=0, row=1)

e1 = Entry(tab1, bd=3)
e1.grid(column=1, row=1)

btn_brf = Button(tab1, text ="Start the attack", bd=2, command = print(""))
btn_brf.grid(column=1, row=2)

btn_brf = Button(tab1, text ="Poradnik", bd=2, command = help_brf)
btn_brf.grid(column=1, row=3)

#ip grabber

lbl_c0 = Label(tab2, text="Your e-mail:")
lbl_c0.grid(column=0, row=0)

#console

lbl_d0 = Label(tab3, text="Last actions:")
lbl_d0.grid(column=0, row=0)

cns = Scrollbar (tab3, bg='lightgray')
cns.grid(column=1, row=0)

#if action != lst_action:
#    cns.insert(END, str(action))


tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

window.mainloop()
```

Does anyone knows how to add something to scrollbar (logs)???

cns.insert(END, print("something")) doesn't work.

I'm also open to suggestions about what I should change in the code

Is there any web-page where i could find out how to do that?

it would be nice if someone sent it to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't add anything to a scrollbar. Well, technically you can but it serves no purpose. Are you asking  how to get the scrollbar to scroll a group of widgets, or how to scroll a single widget?

Comment: I want to add an event log to my program or make redirect from gui to terminal.

Comment: Then you need `tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText` instead of `Scrollbar`.

Comment: Thank you so much for help.